# Drupal Hierarchical Content

Tags: drupal, cck, taxonomy

I am currently looking at using either the Taxonomy or CCK module on my Drupal site as a means to create a hierarchical system. However, I'm a little confused on which one would best suit my needs, or if there is something else that would work better.

Basically, there will be probably 70 or so "mini-sites" on the website I'm working on, each with a landing page and about 5 sub-pages of detailed information. I need a way to mark those sub-pages as being sub-pages of their parent page, as well as create a menu system to navigate between them.

What is the best way this could be done? Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the Book module?  It might take a bit of theme-adjusting to get it to look right it seems to be how most people settle on displaying this type of page structure.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, Organic Groups and/or Spaces can be a good alternatives, since it'd allow you to easily control themes, permissions and other settings in a mini-site basis.

Each Mini-site would be an OG node and/or a space, and subpages could be organized in tree structure as well, using Book module from Drupal Core.

Comment: but since you'll have few pages per mini-site, i guess OG will be enough. if you need to assign people to update/mantain each mini-site, OG will surly help you later. try it.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is the book module. It gives a way to organise hierarchical content in a book manner. There are 2 blocks generated automatically: the book navigation and the book outline which gives, for each page, a link to the previous and the next content.

For more information drupal handbook: http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/book